# Hide console window when executing a .exe with arguments

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application

I've added a "start review" context menu item for .pdf files.

In the registry I've added this as the command:

```
"c:\myscript\abc.exe" "%1"
```

The .exe is a C# application built in C# .NET.

The issue is that whenever I right-click a PDF file and choose the "start review" menu item, I get a black command window opening. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To always hide the console, you can go to *Project > Properties* and change the *Output type* to *Windows Application*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the output type to "Windows Application". The following link should help...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s3awkzkh(v=vs.100).aspx

Good Luck!